# Regex remove everything before the first space occurrence in a line?

Tags: regex, notepad++, openoffice-calc

I would like to remove all the characters before the first space occurrence for each line.

Sample of initial text:

- 2:2 My dog is good.
- 1:234 My cat is bad
- 14:2 My frog is bad but it loves my garden.

Result must be:

- My dog is good.
- My cat is bad
- My frog is bad but it loves my garden

What regular expression would you use to achieve this result using OpenOffice Calc or Notepad++?

Answer (score 11):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\S+\s+(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  \S+       : 1 or more non space character
  \s+       : 1 or more space character
  (.+)      : group 1, 1 or more any character (ie. rest of the line)
$           : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      : content of group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
My dog is good.
My cat is bad
My frog is bad but it loves my garden.
```

Answer (score 6):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> to open Find and replace dialog
- Write `^.*?\s+(.*)$` in 'find what' textbox
- Write `$1` in 'Replace With' textbox
- Check `Regular Expression` radio button OR press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>
- You can click on <kbd>Find Next</kbd> button to verify whether its working correctly (to find matches)
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> button if it looks good OR press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

Explanation:

- `^` : Match from beginning of line
- `.*?\s+`: Match anything, any number of times until a space (or more spaces) is encountered
- `(.*)`: Capture everything after those spaces
- `$`: Match till end of the line
- `$1`: Access the above captured strings from line